# Binding between Data template and ListBox - Windows Phone

Tags: binding, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

I'm having problems to do a binding in Windows Phone. Hope you can help me.

I have the following Data Template:

> `<DataTemplate>`
>
> > `<TextBox Name="txt1"/>`
> > `<TextBox Name="txt2"/>`
> > `</DataTemplate>`

I have a ListBox that receives the following Class in the ItemsSource Property:

```
public class Product
{

    private int _id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

}
```

Is there anyway to bind the Text property with the Object of the ListBoxItem like...

> `<TextBox Name="txt1" Text={Binding ElementName=ListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Product.Name}/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a working example 
xaml:
Here's the code

```
<Grid x:Name="gdTest" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="5,0,5,0" >
    <ListBox Width="400" Margin="10" x:Name="lstDemo">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id}" Margin="20" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="20"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

xaml.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using StackOverFlowTestApp.Resources;
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Phone.UserData;
using Windows.UI;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace StackOverFlowTestApp
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        private SoundEffect effect;
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<Product> liProd = new List<Product>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                liProd.Add(new Product()
                {
                    Id = i,
                    Name = "Anobik" + i.ToString()
                });
            }

            lstDemo.ItemsSource = liProd;

        }


    }

    public class Product
    {

        private int _id;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

    }


    }
```

if you require any more explanation then let me know.

Comment: This help me a lot to understand some things. Thank you a lot! I have another problem, hope you can help me. It's a similar context. Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838053/binding-between-resources-datatemplate-and-listbox-datatemplate-windows-phone