# Binding between Resources.DataTemplate and ListBox.DataTemplate - Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I'm having problems to do a binding in Windows Phone. Hope you can help me.

I have the following Data Template in App.xaml:

> `<Application.Resources>`
>   `<DataTemplate>`
>   `<TextBox Name="txt1"/>`
>   `<TextBox Name="txt2"/>`
>   `</DataTemplate>`
>   `</Application.Resources>`

I have a ListBox with the following Data Template:

> `<ListBox>`
>   `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`
>   `<DataTemplate>`
>   `<TextBox Name="txt1"/>`
>   `<TextBox Name="txt2"/>`
>   `</DataTemplate>`
>   `<ListBox.ItemTemplate>`
>   `<ListBox>`

The ListBox receives the following Class in the ItemsSource Property:

```
public class Product
{

   private int _id;
   public int Id
   {
       get { return _id; }
       set { _id = value; }
   }

   private string _name;

   public string Name
   {
       get { return _name; }
       set { _name = value; }
   }

}
```

Is there anyway to bind the Resources.TextBox.Text property with the Object of the ListBoxItem like...

> `<Application.Resources>`
>   `<TextBox Name="txt1" Text={Binding ElementName=ListBox, Path=SelectedItem.Product.Name}/>`
>   `</Application.Resources>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I couldn't Bind the properties thru xaml, but I did it thru code.

I have the DataTemplate in a CustomMessageBox. So, I got the Textbox inside the CustomMessageBox with a method which I created:

```
    public T SearchControl<T>(DependencyObject parent, string nameControl)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {

        if (parent == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameControl))
            return null;

        if (parent is T && ((FrameworkElement)parent).Name == nameControl)
            return parent as T;

        int totalControles = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);

        for (int i = 0; i < totalControles; i++)
        {

            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);

            T control = BuscarControl<T>(child, nameControl);

            if (control != null)
                return control;

        }

        return null;

    }
```

So, I just called the method and assigned the value that I wanted:

```
(SearchControl<TextBox>(CustomMessageBox, "txt1")).Text = Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use ElementName binding when the item is not in the same NameScope.
The easiest way to do what you want is probably to bind SelectedItem to a property in your viewmodel and use this property to bind the Text of your TextBox.

Comment: How about using an IValueConverter?